# Query isn't returning all of the possible results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem where MySQL LIKE isn't returning all of the possible results. I have the code below:

```
<?php
$query  = "SELECT `user_id`,
                  `rank`, 
                  `habbo_name`,
                  `rating`,
                  `branch` 
             FROM `personnel` 
            WHERE status='active' AND
                  rating='(DIROPS)' 
         ORDER BY `habbo_name`";

$result = $con->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
    echo "<b>DIROPS:</b>&nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['habbo_name']) . "<br>";
}

$query  = "SELECT `user_id`, 
                  `rank`, 
                  `habbo_name`, 
                  `rating`, 
                  `branch` 
             FROM `personnel` 
            WHERE status='active' AND 
                  rating='(CO TECOM)' AND 
                  `branch`='usmc' 
         ORDER BY `habbo_name`";

$result = $con->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
    echo "<b>CO TECOM:</b>&nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['habbo_name']) . "<br>";
}

$query  = "SELECT `user_id`, 
                  `rank`, 
                  `habbo_name`, 
                  `rating`, 
                  `branch` 
             FROM `personnel` 
            WHERE status='active' AND 
                  rating='(XO TECOM)' AND 
                  `branch`='usmc' 
         ORDER BY `habbo_name`";

$result = $con->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
    echo "<b>XO TECOM:</b>&nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['habbo_name']) . "<br>";
}
?>
<br>
<?php
$query  = "SELECT `user_id`, 
                  `rank`, 
                  `habbo_name`, 
                  `rating`, 
                  `branch` 
             FROM `personnel` 
            WHERE status='active' AND 
                  `rating` LIKE '%(TECOM%'  OR 
                  `rating` LIKE '%/TECOM%'  AND 
                  status='active' 
         ORDER BY `habbo_name`";

$result = $con->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
    echo "<b>TECOM:</b>&nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['habbo_name']) . "<br>";
}
?>
```

This, as far as I know, should print out the people who have rating set as (DIROPS), (CO TECOM), (XO TECOM) and then (TECOM or /TECOM).

The problem I have is that only DIROPS and a couple of the others are being returned. This is the result I get from that code:

[image]

Could anyone let me know where I am going wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: Records it should be showing :-

> ```
> TEO-emo12 (DIROPS)
> RockerManiac123 (CO TECOM) 
> Rach-L (Lugn)  (XO TECOM)
> Reyess  (TECOM)
> zachary1142 (AuXHiDef-) (TECOM) 
> norsk.no (TECOM)
> lordoftjefly (mingrana) (PPO/TECOM)
> spen1000 (TECOM/DI)
> ```

Comment: Edit: added records it should be displaying

Comment: Do you need so many queries? Wouldn't one do?

Comment: Performance isn't an issue and I'm a newbie, so it's much easier for me to split it up into separate queries. Not to mention they're searching for different things in the `rating` column and then echoing it out with a different prefix.

Comment: [**Don't forget to see the Stackoverflow TOUR it will guide you on how to best use this website.**](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 0):

you should use one query instead of running same query multiple times for each condition , wrap all your `rating` conditions in a group with a parent `AND` operator and just loop through the result set ignore the multiple loops it will effect  the execution time

```
SELECT `user_id`, 
                  `rank`, 
                  `habbo_name`, 
                  `rating`, 
                  `branch` 
             FROM `personnel` 
            WHERE status='active' AND (
                  `rating` LIKE '%(DIROPS)%' OR 
                  `rating` LIKE '%(CO TECOM)%' OR                      
                  `rating` LIKE '%(XO TECOM)%'   OR
                  `rating` LIKE '%(TECOM%'  OR 
                  `rating` LIKE '%/TECOM%' 
                 ) AND  `branch`='usmc' 
         ORDER BY `habbo_name`
```

OR

```
 SELECT `user_id`, 
                  `rank`, 
                  `habbo_name`, 
                  `rating`, 
                  `branch` 
             FROM `personnel` 
            WHERE status='active' AND (
                  `rating` LIKE '%(DIROPS)%' OR 
                  `rating` LIKE '%(TECOM%'  OR 
                  `rating` LIKE '%/TECOM%' 
                 ) OR `rating`   IN
 (SELECT `rating` FROM `personnel` WHERE `branch`='usmc' 
  AND ( `rating` ='(CO TECOM)' OR `rating` ='(XO TECOM)'))   
         ORDER BY `habbo_name`
```

Comment: why don't u simple group it instead of making a new select? Just curious.